# Getting the Volume of an Uneven Mesh

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigid-body-dynamics

Let's say I have a cube, and that cube breaks apart into 100 different unevenly sized pieces.

How can I get the volume of each of those pieces compared to the cube's volume?

Using this in order to get the mass of each piece; for example, if the large cube is 100 mass, then the largest piece might be 30 and there might be some that are 0.2, etc...

Using C# and Unity with Rigidbodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/52664/how-would-one-calculate-a-3d-mesh-volume-in-unity.html), this can be used to calculate the volume of an arbitrary 3D mesh.

```
public float SignedVolumeOfTriangle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
 {
     float v321 = p3.x * p2.y * p1.z;
     float v231 = p2.x * p3.y * p1.z;
     float v312 = p3.x * p1.y * p2.z;
     float v132 = p1.x * p3.y * p2.z;
     float v213 = p2.x * p1.y * p3.z;
     float v123 = p1.x * p2.y * p3.z;
     return (1.0f / 6.0f) * (-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123);
 }

 public float VolumeOfMesh(Mesh mesh)
 {
     float volume = 0;
     Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
     int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
     for (int i = 0; i &lt; mesh.triangles.Length; i += 3)
     {
         Vector3 p1 = vertices[triangles[i + 0]];
         Vector3 p2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
         Vector3 p3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
         volume += SignedVolumeOfTriangle(p1, p2, p3);
     }
     return Mathf.Abs(volume);
 }
```

With `VolumeOfMesh` you can calculate the volume of each piece, and then sum them up to get the volume of the original shape.