# Calculating the weight of an object irrespective of the triangle or vertices count in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have a meat piece which I want to weigh. Now there can be anything like fish, cheese, or other items that we can cut and measure. I want the weight to be determined by myself instead of determining from getting the surface of the item as it varies with different tris count.
Currently, I am calculating the weight from the following code.

```
public static float CalculateSurfaceArea(Mesh mesh)
{
    var triangles = mesh.triangles;
    var vertices = mesh.vertices;

    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
    {
        Vector3 corner = vertices[triangles[i]];
        Vector3 a = vertices[triangles[i + 1]] - corner;
        Vector3 b = vertices[triangles[i + 2]] - corner;

        sum += Vector3.Cross(a, b).magnitude;
    }
    // weightMultiplier is a constant value for getting a reasonable weight value.
    return (float)(sum / 2.0) * weightMultiplier;
}
```

So if there's a meat piece like bellow and I want it to be a weight of let's say **3kg(6.6lb)**

[image]

then when I cut it into half it should give me values respectively **(1.5kg)**.

[image]

So I want the weighing factor to be in my control so that if in the future we have really detailed high poly items the weight shouldn't get affected by that.

Comment: Your actual problem appears to be that you need to calculate the volume of your meshes, not the surface area. Calculating surface area gets you nowhere in this case, because - as you found out - cutting something into pieces does not change its volume but increases its surface area. And this is actually harder than it sounds, because 3d meshes don't actually need to be fully enclosed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the Volume of an Uneven Mesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106318/getting-the-volume-of-an-uneven-mesh/106320#106320) (mass is volume multiplied by the density of the substance the object is made of)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124381/discussion-on-question-by-syed-munim-raza-calculating-the-weight-of-an-object-ir).